# dynamicViewPanel - get handle of view using var in xp:dominoView

Tags: xpages

I am trying to hide the first column of my view displayed in dynamicviewpanel by selecting a view name in combo box.
However, it keeps giving me reference error.

Script interpreter error, **line=1, col=8: [ReferenceError] 'view11' not found**.

### Here is my code:

```
<xe:dynamicViewPanel role="presentation" rows="10" id="dynamicViewPanel1">
    <xe:this.facets>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
            xp:key="headerPager" id="pager3">
        </xp:pager>
    </xe:this.facets>
    <xe:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view11"
            viewName="#{viewScope.viewName}"
            databaseName="APSE\Arun\Mgmt.nsf"
            postOpenView="#{javascript:view11.removeColumn(1);}">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xe:this.data>
</xe:dynamicViewPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you first need to get a handle to the view. While your javascript is inside the view control, it's not self-aware.

So, try

```
var myView:NotesView = getComponent("view11");
myview.removeColumn(1);
```

in the Javascript instead.

Alternatively, select the columns you actually want by programmatic name instead of removing one based on location, as you'd have to change the XPage code if you ever changed the column order on the back end.